# Two valid certificates equal one invalid certificate

Tags: windows, ssl, centos, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm fairly new to the whole certificate shebang and not a versed Linux admin.
In our company, we run a Windows domain, but we also have some CentOS servers for different services.
On one of said servers we have our ticket system, which is browser based. I want to certify it with a certificate, signed by our Windows root CA, but no matter what I do, the certificate is shown as invalid in the browser.
Funny enough, both certificates in the chain (CA -> server) are shown as valid.
I already did the following:

- start certificate process from scratch
- tried different certificate formats (.cer, .pem)
- verified server cert with root cert
- checked validity with openssl (OK)
- checked SSL connection with openssl, no issues
- added root cert to Linux server trusted CA store
- recreated cert chain (of 2)
- restarted Apache over and over
- reset browser cache
- tried different browser
- checked DNS entries
- checked, if root CA is trusted in Windows (it is)
- manually installed server cert in my browser

Both the server cert and the root cert show up as valid in the browser, with the correct relation.

I'm completely lost here. Is there some key step I forgot and not one of the ~30 guides I read forgot to mention?
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some information:
Did you check the SSL connection from outside the server?
Did you verify the RootCA cert is inside the cert-store of the server (sometimes it is rejected without error messages)?

I would check the reason for rejecting the certificate in the browser (FireFox is usually more informative than Chrome), and look for the error-code.
Reasons can be (some of which you have already verified):
Wrong certificate properties (missing the required values in the "usage" attribute)
Wrong domain name
Expired certificate
Certificate could not be verified on the client-side

See this image as an example of an error code:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/165314/71407838-14f55a00-2634-11ea-8a30-c119d2eb1eb1.png

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As noted in the main text, yes, I added the root cert to the server store (added root cert to Linux server trusted CA store). But your hint with checking the connection from outside the server was good! It seems my domain joined Windows client doesn't trust the root CA enough. I get the message that there's a self signed cert in the chain, even though the root CA signed the server cert. I checked and the root cert IS in fact in the domain trusted store.